# lookup on table excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel table with user data and when they are travelling in the month:

```
 User    01/01/2019    02/01/2019   03/01/2019    04/01/2019    05/01/2019
 Joe                        A           X             X              X
 Jane                                                 A              X
 Bob         A              X           X             Z
```

Where A is the first in a series of travelling days away that terminates at Z.

In a separate sheet I have a summary, where I want to know for a specific day, who is starting to travel.

i.e.

```
Date Outbound    Name
02/01/2019       Joe
```

If I populate date outbound I would like it to return the name of the person with an "A" in the column corresponding to that date.

I can't for the life of me work it out with Index, matches or VLookup.
I'm not precious about the format of the sheet, it's just what's been inherited.

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: is there a mximum number of users?  I am assuming multiple people can be travelling on the same day. Is there a limit to this number?

Comment: Hi, yes, it's possible multiple users could be travelling on the same day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro will find multiple names for a given date.

```
Function GetNameofTraveler(CellIn)

SourceShtNm = "Sheet1"  ' <---- Name of the shet that has the traveller data
DateRow = 1 ' <----- Chnage to match the row that has the travel dates
NameCol = 1 ' <----- Chnage to match the column that has the names

Set Datasheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceShtNm)

TargetDate = CellIn.Value

'* Get the range for the traveler data
LastCol = Datasheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
LastRow = Datasheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count


NameList = ""
NumNames = 0
' Look for the date that matches
For i = 1 To LastCol
    If Datasheet.Cells(DateRow, i).Value = TargetDate Then
        ' Look for names on rows that have an "A"
        For j = 1 To LastRow
            If UCase(Datasheet.Cells(j, i)) = "A" Then
                NameList = NameList + Datasheet.Cells(j, NameCol) + vbLf
                NumNames = NumNames + 1
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

If NumNames = 0 Then
    NameList = "  "
End If
GetNameofTraveler = Left(NameList, Len(NameList) - 1)

End Function
```

In the cell use

```
=GetNameofTraveler(A2)
```

where A2 has the date of interest.

Traveler sheet looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$4)/(INDEX($B$2:$F$4,0,MATCH($A$8,$B$1:$F$1,0))="A"),ROW(A1)))
```

Aggregate with function 15 performs array like operations.  As such do not use full column references within the array function or you will windup with a lot of excess calculations.

[image: POC]

Adjust the cell references to suit your data.  copy down as required to get multiple names.  to avoid an error message when a departure is not found or you are beyond the number of names departing in the day, wrap the whole thing in an IFERROR function as follows:

```
=IFERROR(=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$4)/(INDEX($B$2:$F$4,0,MATCH($A$8,$B$1:$F$1,0))="A"),ROW(A1))),"NOT FOUND")
```

Change "NOT FOUND" to "" if you prefer blanks or your own message.

Answer (score 0):

If only there is only one user per date, you can use the following:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("A",INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($H$3,A1:F1,0)),"$1","")&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($H$3,A1:F1,0)),"$1","")),0),1))
```

Could be that there is a smaller version, but couldn't think of it that quick.
If there are more users per date, I think you need a vba formula.

Answer (score 0):

If Sheet1 looks like this:
[image]

Sheet2 could look like this:
[image]

The formula in column B:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,MATCH("A",OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$B$1:$F$1,),10,1),0)-1,0)
```

The 10 is the depth of the search.

If you need more than one per date, you'll need a VBA macro.